Duplicated content risk for translated content: how much unique content do I need to have per article?
I have 2 websites in The Netherlands, lets call them example1.nl and example2.nl. They both have articles on the same topics. I wrote all the articles myself.
I want to go international with example1. Meaning, I want to translate all the content and offer it in multiple languages (example1 gets way more traffic and already has a decent backlink profile). I've coded everything to include the hreflang tags etc. The problem is, is that I want to use the content from example2. This is because the content is generally better, newer and more up to date.

How much risk am I taking with taking the content from example2, translating it into different languages and using it on different locales of example1?
How many unique words or unique content per 1000 words would I need to add to make it 'unique' so that it doesn't get penalized for duplicated content?

Since example2 pretty much gets about 10% of the total traffic, I was also thinking of just killing the site with a 301 redirect. But I only want to do that if the risk of getting penalties on example1 is too high.
